# Could someone maybe point me in the direction of a decent tutorial on how to create a wordpress plugin that is compatible with another plugin please?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-contact-form-7

I need to add an input field that makes use of intl-tel-input to verify the entered cellphone number, an additional button that sends an sms to that cellphone number. And then a second input for the code that has been sent to that sms. Implementing that is fairly straight forward and got it up and running in a regular html form along with some php files.

The problem I have currently is that the client insists on using the Contact Form 7 plugin. So I need to integrate that without breaking the plugin.

I'm extremely inexperienced when it comes to wordpress. And my deadline is tomorrow morning...Can anyone perhaps point me in the direction of some decent tutorials on how to add either create a plugin that is compatible with another plugin, or just advice in general on how to best approach this please?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i'd suggest given that timeframe, creating a shortcode for the working form you already have, then redirect the existing submitted CF7 form to a page with that shortcode, then work out later how to integrate the input with CF7 itself... https://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/

Comment: there is no need to write a plugin to do all this.  CF7 is very flexible so you can add custom html to your form.  [Enqueue custom js script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079247/contact-form-7-in-wordpress-how-to-include-javascript-src-in-body/42105807#42105807) to control the various events of your buttons/fields, use ajax if you need to communicate back to the server.